# Apache SVN realtime recommended backup solution

Tags: backup, rsync, svn, incremental-backup, real-time

I have an apache subversion running in production environment, the repository size is around 100 GB. Now I am trying to build a failover standby for the primary SVN server. I have gone through a couple of backup mechanisms, but I couldn't find an ideal one which is apt of my failover setup. Can anyone could suggest me an ideal solution for a realtime backup for svn with easy failover and disaster recovery.

I have the following backup info, but I need to know which is the most recommended one.

- Using svnadmin dump for complete backup. (for 100GB everytime this would be a head ache, restoring is also a pain)
- Using svnadmin dump with incremental backup. (This is my current backup scenario, It take incremental backups on a daily basis)
- rsync the primary svn directory to standby host. (I am not sure about the integrity of files using this mechanism. Any sudden outage on primary could left a corrupted svn repo on secondary.? Im not sure about this)
- Using svnsync for mirroring repositories.

  Please suggest how to move forward with valuable comments.

Thanks 
Arun

Comment: You already have the solutions. Make up your mind and go with it? If your solution really is realtime you already know that some of those are not going to work. You might have to look into other mechanisms for that. The `svnsync` or maybe a different approach like ZFS Snapshots might help you with that. I really don't understand why you're all about backup when you actually want to have a failover/hot standby.

Comment: @Seth, I was finding out all the possible ways and looking for the recommended one which do not cause issues on file integrity. So backup mechanism should be ready to go for standby without too much delay and  data loss. I check ZFS replication instead of snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

`svnadmin hotcopy` is more reliable (and easy) way, than incremental dumps (and, BTW, it "just work").

Rsynced (or by any other way copied on file-level) repositories can't be broken anyway - SVN is transaction-based, you just skip and will not see not finished in Main operation on Backup

Comment: So you are telling like there wont be any file integrity issues if I sync the primary using rsync. What will happen If rsync pull the files during a commit which is not completed.?

Comment: Repository-storage is **transaction-aware in the core** - You can either have or not have full transaction (commit stored) in rsynced file, not "part of commit". But SVN-by nature-tools seems *somehow* better